# Changing the order by which heatmap cluster branches are plotted

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I have 3 heatmaps: each one for a different bacterial species (each one with 3 replicates) growing at different pH: 5.0, 7.4 and 9.8.

**To plot the heatmap**:

```
library(gplots)

heatmap.2(data.scale, key = TRUE, keysize = 1, Rowv = NULL,
  Colv = as.dendrogram(hclust(col.clus, method = "average")),
  density.info = "none", trace = "none", cexCol = "0.95",
  cexRow = "0.59", margins = c(4, 10), col = heat.colors,
  dendrogram = ('column'))
```

In my heatmap (see figure) pH 9.8 appears first separated from pH 5 and pH 7.4. I know it is logical because it is organized by similarity given by euclidean distance. But for visual purposes I want the order of appearence to be pH 5.0, pH 7.4 and pH 9.8, because each heatmap will have the different pH appearing in different orders.

Is there a way to do this with R? Or it is logically impossible?

[image: :]

Comment: It'd be helpful to have a minimal, reproducible example to work with. Please consider editing your question to include appropriate code.

Comment: BenBarnes, is it better?

Comment: The code is still not reproducible, since you do not provide all required objects. When you can copy and paste the code into a fresh R session (without having saved the history) and it works, then the example is reproducible.